# Not able to load one React app into another

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, build, create-react-app

I'm trying to recreate this, (loading one react app into another). In this below example, everything works:

https://react-app-load2.netlify.app/

The main script file is here for loading App1 into App2 is here

```
onsole.log("Hello world!");

const fetchAssets = async () => {
  try {
    console.log("fetchAssets executed");

    const request = await (
      await fetch(`https://react-app-load1.netlify.app/asset-manifest.json`)
    ).json();

    console.log(request, "REQUEST");
    importFilesFromArray(request.entrypoints, "https://react-app-load1.netlify.app/");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error, "error");
    console.error("Error fetching app 1 assets");
  }
};

// Takes the provided array, parses it and loads all of the
// JS and CSS files based on their file extension.
function importFilesFromArray(files, rootURL) {
  console.log(files, "FILES");
  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    if (files[i].endsWith(".js")) {
      importJSFile(rootURL + files[i]);
    } else if (files[i].endsWith(".css")) {
      importCSSFile(rootURL + files[i]);
    }
  }
}

// Imports a single JS file.
function importJSFile(url) {
  console.log(url, "url");
  var jsElement = document.createElement("script");
  jsElement.src = url;
  jsElement.type = "text/javascript";

  var head = document.head;
  head.insertBefore(jsElement, head.childNodes[0]);
}

// Imports a single CSS file.
function importCSSFile(url) {
  var cssElement = document.createElement("link");
  cssElement.href = url;
  cssElement.rel = "stylesheet";
  cssElement.type = "text/css";

  var head = document.head;
  head.insertBefore(cssElement, head.childNodes[0]);
}


window.onload = function () {
  fetchAssets();
};
```

The code for both repos is here

- https://github.com/vincentntang/react-app-load1
- https://github.com/vincentntang/react-app-load2

### The Issue

In the above example, everything works as intended. It does the following:

1. App1 is built and loaded in
2. App2 is built and also loading in App1

In my live work production environment (not shown here), I cannot get #2 to work. I tried changing how the script files load in, and ejected React / unminified it to run some debugging

Not sure how to fix this error as there's not a whole lot of documentation on this issue

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to update the `name` on `package.json` between both repos so they were different. Webpack was using the same namespace as building both apps and it overwrote the existing webpack file